# HaxeFlixel 2 player game: make input code cleaner

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I'm makeing two-player game. `player1` can play with the WASD keys, and `player2` can play with the arrow keys.

**PlayState.hx**

```
package;

import flixel.FlxState;

class PlayState extends FlxState
{
    //basic global varible
    var WindowWidth:Int = 640;
    var WindowHeight:Int = 480;

    //sprites
    var player1:Player;
    var player2:Player;

    override public function create():Void
    {

        player1 = new Player(50, WindowHeight / 2 - 50);
        add(player1);


        player2 = new Player(590, WindowHeight / 2 - 50);
        add(player2);

        super.create();
    }

    override public function update(elapsed:Float):Void
    {
        player1.update();
        player2.update();
        super.update(elapsed);
    }
}
```

**Player.hx**

```
package;

import flixel.FlxSprite;
import flixel.FlxG;
import flixel.util.FlxColor;

class Player extends FlxSprite
{
    public function new(X:Float,Y:Float)
    {
        super(X,Y);
        makeGraphic(20,100,FlxColor.WHITE);
    }

    override public function update(elapsed:Float):Void
    {

        super.update(elapsed);
    }
}
```

In this code, I made a player class. This class is used by both `player1` and `player2` instances.

Currently both players are moved by the arrow keys. But I want to make two players using different keys (arrow keys and WASD keys).

I'm considering two solutions, but I think the both ways are not perfect. It smells of bad code.

Solution 1:
Make `player1` and `player2` classes. They extend the `Player` class and override the `update()` method.

```
class Player1 extends Player
{
    override public function update(elapsed:Float):Void
    {
        //make player1 move by wasd keys.
        super.update(elapsed);
    }
}
class Player1 extends Player
{
    override public function update(elapsed:Float):Void
    {
        //make player2 move by arrow keys.
        super.update(elapsed);
    }
}
```

But if I add the code in `update()`, there will be duplicated code. I want to make two player is completely identical, only different location and keyboard.

Solution 2:
Receive argument in `update()` function which key will use, and use it.

```
override public function update(elapsed:Float, upkey, downkey, rightkey, leftkey):Void
{
    //I will write it psuedo code
    if(upkey.pressed):
        move up
    if(downkey.pressed):
        move down
    if(leftkey.pressed):
        move left
    if(rightkey.pressed):
        move right
    super.update(elapsed);
}
```

But it have to additional argument in the `update()` function. And I think it makes the code more complex.

To me, both seem like bad code. What can I do?

Comment: Please use a spelling checker. In the code snippets, try not to waste (vertical) space.

Comment: (I read `currently both players are moved by arrow key` as *I do have working code, not shown in `Player.update()` because irrelevant here*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parametrizing the keys seems like the correct solution to me. The subclassing approach leads to code duplication and inflexibility. However, you should *not* do that by adding parameters to `update()` - in fact, you *can't*, because the function signature of an overriden method has to match. You would get a compiler error:

> Field update overloads parent class with different or incomplete type
>
> Different number of function arguments

Since it's 4 parameters that are closely related to each other, you might want to bundle them in a structure. By using the [`FlxG.keys.anyPressed()`](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/input/FlxKeyManager.html?#anyPressed) API, which takes an array of keys, we could in theory also allow multiple keys per input:

```
package;

import flixel.FlxG;
import flixel.FlxSprite;
import flixel.util.FlxColor;
import flixel.input.keyboard.FlxKey;

class Player extends FlxSprite
{
    var keys:PlayerKeys;

    public function new(x:Float, y:Float, keys:PlayerKeys)
    {
        super(x, y);
        makeGraphic(20, 100, FlxColor.WHITE);
    }

    override public function update(elapsed:Float):Void
    {
        if (FlxG.keys.anyPressed(keys.up)) { /* move up */ }
        if (FlxG.keys.anyPressed(keys.down)) { /* move down */ }
        if (FlxG.keys.anyPressed(keys.left)) { /* move left */ }
        if (FlxG.keys.anyPressed(keys.right)) { /* move right */ }

        super.update(elapsed);
    }
}

typedef PlayerKeys = {
    up:Array<FlxKey>,
    down:Array<FlxKey>,
    left:Array<FlxKey>,
    right:Array<FlxKey>
}
```

And to construct the player instances:

```
player1 = new Player(x, y, {up: [UP], down: [DOWN], left: [LEFT], right: [RIGHT]});
player2 = new Player(x, y, {up: [W], down: [S], left: [A], right: [D]});
```

---

There's two other issues with your code:

- You `update()` your players manually in `PlayState` - Flixel already does that when you call `super.update()`, since you've `add()`ed the players to the state. This means the players end up being updated twice per frame.
- You manually added variables for `WindowWidth` and `WindowHeight`, which are already available globally via `FlxG.width` and `FlxG.height`.

Comment: thank you so much. i really appreciate. it was lot of help.